# How to collect C# code coverage by running tests in Python?

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I want to implement an algorithm in `C#` but test it in `Python` using `python.net` & `pytest` which I'm familiar with (and I also have a reference implementation in `Python` with which I want to compare outputs), so the question is: is there a way to compile `C#` to a DLL, import it in `Python` with `python.net`, run tests in `Python` and collect coverage of `C#` code being invoked during this process?

For example let's consider I have `myclass.cs` file

```cs
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static int mymethod(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

after that I compile it with [`mcs`](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/)

```bash
> mcs -t:library myclass.cs
```

getting `myclass.dll` which I import using `python.net` library in a `binding.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pythonnet

pythonnet.load()
from System import Reflection

Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(str(Path(__file__).parent / 'myclass.dll'))
import mynamespace

mymethod = mynamespace.MyClass.mymethod
```

after that in my `test.py`

```py
from binding import mymethod


def test_mymethod():
    assert mymethod(1, 2) == 3
```

After running

```bash
> pytest test.py
```

I'm getting expected

```bash
...
test.py .                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

======================================================================= 1 passed in 0.41s ========================================================================
```

so far so good, but the question is how to get the coverage of original `myclass.cs` file? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I finally found a great [dotnet-coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-coverage) tool which can be installed with

```bash
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage
```

and after that we can run `Python` tests with `pytest` (which call compiled `C#` code using `python.net`) and collect resulting coverage of `C#` project as easy as

```bash
> dotnet coverage collect pytest --output-format cobertura --output-format coverage.xml
```

which I can then for example upload to [`codecov` service](https://app.codecov.io).